# create a deployment package for Service Fabric that includes all artifacts necessary to run the designed workflows at runtime

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How to create a deployment package for Service Fabric that includes all artifacts necessary to run the designed workflows at run-time?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to package a service fabric application by building a solution in release mode (for example). This section can be added to the `.sfproj` file to achieve the goal:

```
<Target Name="ReleaseAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
   <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectPath)" Targets="Package" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a Service Fabric application package you need to run the "Package" target on the sfproj file.

```
msbuild app.sfproj /t:Package
```

This will create a "pkg" directory next to the sfproj file with all the necessary files.

Comment: You can also do this through the user interface in Visual Studio by right-clicking the Application project and selecting the "Package" menu item in the context menu.

Comment: @MattThalman not really. you cannot specify which applicationparameters file to use when you do that