# How can I package a Service Fabric application from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, powershell-cmdlet

I'd like to automate the package and publish steps for my service fabric application, but I can't find any cmdlets that would let me generate the pkg\Debug dir in the ServiceFabricSDK.psm1 module. Any hints?

The closest I could get is:

```
New-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage
```

but this gets the pkg\Debug dir as an input and I'm looking for a script that has that outputs the contents of this dir, essentially mimicking the Visual Studio "Package" command.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be through a cmdlet?

To generate the package through the command line, you can call the "Package"  target on the sfproj file.

See my answer on [create a deployment package for Service Fabric that includes all artifacts necessary to run the designed workflows at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543039/create-a-deployment-package-for-service-fabric-that-includes-all-artifacts-neces/36543474#36543474)

Comment: Not necessarily, as long as I can script it, it's fine. Thanks for the link! I missed it in my searches.