# Packaging Service Fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When building a Service Fabric application on a build server, is there a way to get a deployment package built with `.sfproj` / nuget combination?
Digging around found that there's a `.sfpkg` option, but it is not clear how to build that using MSBuild.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543039/create-a-deployment-package-for-service-fabric-that-includes-all-artifacts-neces/36543474

Comment: Precisely what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible duplicate is showing how it package a service fabric application from a command line. I was after achieving the same when building a solution in release mode. This section can be added to the `.sfproj` file to achieve the goal:

```
<Target Name="ReleaseAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
   <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectPath)" Targets="Package" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Can you copy your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543039/create-a-deployment-package-for-service-fabric-that-includes-all-artifacts-neces/36543474 as well?

Comment: Done Philip. Did you find it helpful? :)

Comment: Don't need it yet, but I can see this being helpful when setting up deployment infrastructure for ASF.  But in case this questions is closed as a dup, wanted to make sure your answer was on the other question as well so I don't lose it :)