# Automate deployment of Service Fabric project without TFS or VSTS

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I know you can [publish a Service Fabric application](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-publish-app-remote-cluster/) written in C# using Visual Studio, and I have read this article on [using TFS or VSTS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/) to set up continuous integration DevOps builds of a Service Fabric application.

**How can I just do this all manually using PowerShell?** I know I can do the following using PowerShell from [this article on deployment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-automate-powershell/):

- Use Visual Studio to package the project.
- Transfer the package to a remote server.
- Use the PowerShell script examples in the article to deploy the package while I am in the context of the remote server.

Instead, here are two bits I can't seem to figure out which would assist me in doing this from PowerShell:

- Using PowerShell, how can I package my Service Fabric project the same way you can when you are in the context of Visual Studio?
- Using PowerShell, how can I remotely deploy my Service Fabric project the same way you can when you are in the context of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the package through the command line, you can call the "Package" target on the sfproj file.

See my answer on [create a deployment package for Service Fabric that includes all artifacts necessary to run the designed workflows at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543039/create-a-deployment-package-for-service-fabric-that-includes-all-artifacts-neces/36543474#36543474)

Then follow the instructions from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications/ as blackSphere suggested.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks! `msbuild app.sfproj /t:Package` was what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't seen this link, take a look at [Deploy and Remove Packages using Powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications/) article.

> Suppose you have a folder named MyApplicationType that contains the necessary application manifest, service manifests, and code/config/data packages. The Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage command uploads the package to the cluster Image Store

That takes a directory and uploads it. Then you have to tell it to take that image and use it in the application.

> The Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType command returns only after the system has successfully copied the application package. How long this takes depends on the contents of the application package. If needed, the -TimeoutSec parameter can be used to supply a longer timeout.

After you register it you can create the application:

> You can instantiate an application by using any application type version that has been registered successfully through the New-ServiceFabricApplication command

Comment: You misunderstood my question, so let me rephrase. Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage requires you to have an application package. How can I create the package outside of Visual Studio, using PowerShell? I need to script a way to build the package outside of Visual Studio. How?